# Long running lambda wait for response times out in Airflow

Tags: aws-lambda, boto3, airflow

We invoke certain lambdas via an Airflow operator. In the operator, a call to `lambda.invoke` in the boto3 library is made (via the `AwsLambdaHook`).

However, one of the lambdas has a long running time (10-15 mins). Initially the operator received a boto3 timeout exception due to the fact that the default timeout on `invoke` is 60 seconds.

So we extended the `AwsLambdaHook` to allow for configuration to be passed to the `boto` client (code for reference):

```py
from airflow.contrib.hooks.aws_hook import AwsHook


class AwsLambdaHook(AwsHook):
    """
    Interact with AWS Lambda

    :param function_name: AWS Lambda Function Name
    :type function_name: str
    :param region_name: AWS Region Name (example: us-west-2)
    :type region_name: str
    :param log_type: Tail Invocation Request
    :type log_type: str
    :param qualifier: AWS Lambda Function Version or Alias Name
    :type qualifier: str
    :param invocation_type: AWS Lambda Invocation Type (RequestResponse, Event etc)
    :type invocation_type: str
    :param config: Config to pass to the lambda connection
    :type config: boto3.Config
    """

    def __init__(
        self,
        function_name,
        region_name=None,
        log_type="None",
        qualifier="$LATEST",
        invocation_type="RequestResponse",
        config=None,
        *args,
        **kwargs
    ):
        self.function_name = function_name
        self.region_name = region_name
        self.log_type = log_type
        self.invocation_type = invocation_type
        self.qualifier = qualifier
        self.config = config
        super(AwsLambdaHook, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

    def get_conn(self):
        self.conn = self.get_client_type("lambda", self.region_name, self.config)
        return self.conn

    def invoke_lambda(self, payload):
        """
        Invoke Lambda Function
        """

        awslambda_conn = self.get_conn()

        response = awslambda_conn.invoke(
            FunctionName=self.function_name,
            InvocationType=self.invocation_type,
            LogType=self.log_type,
            Payload=payload,
            Qualifier=self.qualifier,
        )

        return response
```

And we pass the following config:

```py
from botocore.client import Config

config_dict = {"connect_timeout": 5, "read_timeout": 900}
config = Config(**config_dict)
```

Now, the operator no longer recieves a boto3 timeout exception. However, it ended up hitting our Airflow task execution timeout (configured to 1 hour).
In the logs I saw the following:

```
[2019-10-25 07:52:05,172] {aws_lambda_operator.py:114} INFO - AWS Lambda: invoking Lambdas20
[2019-10-25 07:52:05,316] {logging_mixin.py:95} INFO - [[34m2019-10-25 07:52:05,316[0m] {[34mconnectionpool.py:[0m735} INFO[0m - Starting new HTTPS connection (1): lambda.ap-southeast-1.amazonaws.com[0m
[2019-10-25 08:07:07,097] {logging_mixin.py:95} INFO - [[34m2019-10-25 08:07:07,097[0m] {[34mconnectionpool.py:[0m735} INFO[0m - Starting new HTTPS connection (2): lambda.ap-southeast-1.amazonaws.com[0m
[2019-10-25 08:22:08,489] {logging_mixin.py:95} INFO - [[34m2019-10-25 08:22:08,489[0m] {[34mconnectionpool.py:[0m735} INFO[0m - Starting new HTTPS connection (3): lambda.ap-southeast-1.amazonaws.com[0m
[2019-10-25 08:37:11,402] {logging_mixin.py:95} INFO - [[34m2019-10-25 08:37:11,402[0m] {[34mconnectionpool.py:[0m735} INFO[0m - Starting new HTTPS connection (4): lambda.ap-southeast-1.amazonaws.com[0m
[2019-10-25 08:52:05,172] {logging_mixin.py:95} INFO - [[34m2019-10-25 08:52:05,172[0m] {[34mtime
```

It seems as if there is never a response from AWS. The lambda has already completed though. The same lambda code (just working on less data and running in a different region) does work fine with the Lambda operator, so I am pretty sure the problem is not with the lambda.

Now I have 2 questions:

1. Has anyone experienced similar behaviour before of invoking a lambda before? What was the resolution?
2. Is there an alternative approach where we can asynchronously poll the result? I looked in the `boto3` documentation, but it looked like `invoke_async` was deprecated.

Comment: You need response ?

Comment: Yes, I want to know wether the lambda completed succesfully. It is needed before I can start the next operator of the DAG as that depends on the files created.